Proving that for pairs $(X,p)$ consisting of a projective hypersurface and a point, the condition that $X$ contains a line through $p$ is closed.
I am working over a field $k$. Consider the closed subscheme $Z\subset\mathbb{P}^{{n + d \choose d}-1}\times\mathbb{G}(1,n)\times\mathbb{P}^n$ defined informally by $Z=\{(X,L,p):p\in L\subset X\}$. Here we think of $\mathbb{P}^{{n + d \choose d}-1}$ as parameterizing degree $d$ hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^n$ and $\mathbb{G}(1,n)$ is the Grassmannian of lines in $\mathbb{P}^n$. It is not hard to give a precise definition of $Z$, as being cut out by equations expressing the two incidence relations $p\in L$ and $L\subset X$.
Now consider the projection map $\pi:\mathbb{P}^{{n + d \choose d}-1}\times\mathbb{G}(1,n)\times\mathbb{P}^n\to\mathbb{P}^{{n + d \choose d}-1}\times\mathbb{P}^n$. I want to show that $\pi(Z)$ is closed. By Chevalley's Theorem it is constructible, so it's enough to show that it is closed under specialization. This is where I am stuck.
Question: How do I prove $\pi(Z)$ is closed under specialization?
(This question comes from trying to solve exercise 12.3.L in Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry)

Do you see why $\pi$ is the base change of a proper map? Are you comfortable with using this method to show a map is proper?

I know that base changes of proper morphisms are proper and I know that projective $k$-schemes are proper over $k$. I guess $\mathbb{G(1,n)}$ is proper over $k$? I'm not sure I know how to prove this, but I could try. Then the projection map above is a base change of $\mathbb{G(n,1)}\to Spec(k)$ so it's closed and I wouldn't need Chevalley's Theorem. Is that it?

Of course the Grassmannian is projective: it is cut out by the Plucker equations in the Plucker projective space.

Thanks! But I don't know about the Plucker embedding yet, that's in Chapter 16 of Vakil's book. In Exercise 12.3.L the hint is to use Chevalley's Theorem, so I was hoping to show the image is closed under specialization.
